# Infinite scroll repeatition of same ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following is my function which I am using to load data as per < last id of li `.post-list` but still I am getting repetition of same ids that were pulled before. Kindly let me know how can I resolve this issue so the old  ids doesn't load/repeat itself again.:

[image]

```
function loadData() 
{ 
    $('div.postloader').html('<img src="img/loader.gif">');
    $.post("getData.php?lastID=" + $(".post-list:last").attr("id"),     
    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".post-list:last").after(data);            
        }
        $('div.postloader').empty();
    });
};
```

Comment: You should prevent `$.post` being called repeatedly, until the request comes back (since it's just a snippet of your code - my guess is that loadData is called multiple times?)

Comment: Just a quick observation, ids cannot start with a number http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: there is likely a problem with `getData.php`. One possible solution is to store the last ID in a global javascript variable and increment that, instead of selecting the last ID from the DOM

Comment: hay do you got any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible soution to prevent this is to store the last ID in a global variable in JS and increment that, so you don't have to rely on selecting the right element to find the ID to POST.

Comment: Can you kindly give a quick `code example` of that?

Answer (score 0):

you're pulling the data from the server too fast, try adding a flag that will prevent pulling the items while the request is running:

```
var flagPulling = false;
function loadData() { 
    if( flagPulling ) {
        return;
    }
    flagPulling = true;
    $('div.postloader').html('<img src="http://www.zesteve.com/img/loader.gif">');
    $.post("/getData.php?lastID=" + $(".post-list:last").attr("id"), function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            $(".post-list:last").after(data);            
        }
       $('div.postloader').empty();
       flagPulling = false;
    });
};
```